# Matching with multi-level multiple membership data

Tags: nested, matching, multilevel-analysis

I am designing a within multi-level study in which my data has both nested and multiple-membership structure. The subjects are multimembers of V1 and also are nested in V2.The subjects are all from one year. When applying matching or weighting, should I take the multiple membership into account? if yes, the question would be how? or should I apply matching without taking it into account and then run a multiple membership multi-level regression on the output from matching?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your concrete use case, it's hard to recommend specific sources. But check out "cross-classified multilevel analysis". I think that's what you're referring to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).